# Date formatting in django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

Ok so I have a backend for an app written in ruby on rails and I just rewrote the backend in python using django but its not working because the date time formatting is different.

so in rails the formatting looks like

```
2015-01-14 05:14:44 UTC
```

and in python it looks like

```
2015-01-19T17:58:08.991Z
```

right now I have model in django that looks like

```
date = models.DateTimeField()
```

now when I got modelobject.date it needs to be in the same formatting as in ruby on rails... what do I need to do to reformat the date time?

Comment: So you need to get the date from the field and then convert it into a string that is formatted like in Rails? Or you have the date as a string in the Rails-type format and you need to get it into your database?

Comment: I need to do both. Should I just convert to string and use string replace etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strptime` from `datetime` module to get python compatible date time from your query result using a format string.

So, you'd be doing something like:

```
from datetime import strptime

# ... your code ...

date = strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Checkout this for more on strptime https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Check out this for more formatting options:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can make methods on your model that convert the string using Python's datetime module:

```
import datetime

# ... model definition ...

    def date_from_ruby_string(self, datestring):
        """set date field based on string in ruby format"""
        self.date = datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d %h-%M-%S UTC")

    def ruby_string_from_date(self):
        """return string of date in ruby format"""
        return self.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h-%M-%S UTC")
```